# get_the_date() for translating date format

Tags: translation, localization, date-time

I want to display dates in **Hindi** format like

```
jan 10
```

using `get_the_date()` function. What I have tried so far:

```
echo get_the_date(_e('F j'));
```

which outputs:

```
F jJanuary 10, 2017.
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but no answer accepted, so here goes..

You get weird output, because `_e` just prints "F j" literally and isn't passing it to the function. Hence you get the raw format followed by the default date format.

However, you don't need to use any translation function, because get_the_date() handles it all. Just do:

```
<?php echo get_the_date('F j'); ?>
```

Translations of the months are in the WordPress core translation files. If you have a translation of "October" in Hindi and have your site language set to `hi_IN` it will display the translated date.

See this [recent, similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/316073/cant-translate-the-post-meta-data-date-in-another-language) with some more detail on the date_format option.

Comment: it doesnt work for spanish

Comment: It works for all languages, equally.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
echo get_the_date(__('M d'));
```

**Output:**

Feb 09

```
echo get_the_date(__('M d, Y'));
```

**Output:**

Feb 09, 2017

Comment: It doesn't work in hindi. It output like in hindi : ???? 23

Comment: It shows in hindi if you are selected site language hindi (Dashboard >> Settings >> General)

Comment: But I want both english and hindi on my site when user click on language translate button.. check url : competitionmantra.com

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress date_i18n function comes in handy for none english sites and when using multiple languages/locales. You can find more info on the WordPress code reference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/).

In your case, I would try:

```
<?php echo date_i18n( 'F j', strtotime( get_the_date() ) ); ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_locale/

It allows you to changed the frontend language