# Can't translate the post meta data (Date) in another language

Tags: post-meta, translation, localization

I want to translate the post meta data (date) in chines language for example, September 13, 2017, should be translated as 2017年9月13. But my code gives it in English. Do you see any error? Please help.

Thank you in advance.

```
  $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
        if (get_the_time('U') !== get_the_modified_time('U')) {
            $time_string .= '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
        }

        $time_string = sprintf($time_string,
            esc_attr(get_the_date('c')),
            esc_html(get_the_date()),
            esc_attr(get_the_modified_date('c')),
            esc_html(get_the_modified_date())
        );
        printf(__('<span class="posted-on"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> %3$s</a></span>', 'colormag'), 
            esc_url(get_permalink()), esc_attr(get_the_time()), $time_string
        );
```

Comment: The [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time#Localization) says to use `date_i18n`.

Comment: inside the printf  i used __() to localize. But still the same

Comment: How do I use `date_i18n` ?

Comment: Example is from the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n): `<?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( '11/15-1976' ) ); ?>`

Comment: May you give an example with `printf` please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change any code.

[get_the_date](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) without an argument will use the [date_format](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) option in your WordPress settings. The option `F j, Y` will substitute `F` as "September", but if you have a translation of "September" it will be used.

Comments have suggested the use of [date_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/date_i18n/). This is used **automatically** when you call get_the_date(). Translations of the days and months are in WordPress core and will be used if installed. e.g. The Chinese translation of "September" is [here](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev/zh-cn/default?filters%5Bstatus%5D=either&filters%5Boriginal_id%5D=1367231&filters%5Btranslation_id%5D=32095226),

However, if you want to print **"2017年9月13"** I think you will have to set a custom format in your WordPress settings as:

```
Y年m月d
```

Under Settings > General > Date Format, select "Custom" and enter that into the field. I've tested that and it formats the Chinese characters just fine.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you very much! Yes `date_i18n` and `i10n` are already installed in wordpress as you said. I fixed it from setting after two days. Thank you again! :)

Comment: OK good. Please accept my answer if it's correct.

Comment: Your answer is correct, How do I accept?I newly joined the Forum, I already voted up, a message fleshed  " Your vote is counted but will not appear as your reputation is less. "

Comment: Click the grey tick on the left of the answer, below the up/down arrows

Comment: Your answer seems to be a better choice. But how to use a custom translation for the date, instead of WordPress installed ones. E.g. WordPress installed translations are in their language format, but I want to use my own translation that is written in English letters. So how to use my translation?

Comment: Take a look at "Loco Translate". This allows custom translation files to override installed ones.