# Date translation doesn't work

Tags: php, translation

I would like to translate into French the month of the date I get with the function:

```
get_the_date()
```

I have done several searches and found several solutions but none of them worked so far.

I have tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821998/translate-dated-f-y-hi-function-php
- https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/translating-your-sites-date-format-using-wpml/ (because i use WPML)
- [get_the_date() for translating date format](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256682/get-the-date-for-translating-date-format)
- https://www.skyminds.net/wordpress-afficher-la-date-en-francais-dans-le-theme-sans-utiliser-le-pack-de-langue-ou-setlocale/

Do you have a solution without adding a plugin?

Comment: have you installed the french localisation files for WordPress? You may need to ask other WPML users for help with this as WPML and other 3rd party plugins are offtopic here

Comment: I don't think I have this installed, I'll check with WPML users thanks!